# Adobe Sign API with existing forms

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I have existing forms that have document tags in them.  I need to upload these to adobe sign api and then email them to others to sign.  I have a total of 8 different pdf files (forms) that would need to be signed.  I have found documentation that tells me how to create a new pdf file but not how to use existing ones.  I know I am not the first person to do this or use this api.  I have looked over the documentation and cannot find anything on how to do this.

I have tried to use swagger and the transient document section of the api documentation.  I did not get any results returned back from the post that was in the documentation.  I included a c# tag because I am writing this in C# (.net 7 using REST api)

My question is has anyone had experience with this particular function?

This is some of my existing code

```
 try
{
    String input = @"C:\Test\ACH Form - Tagged.docx";  //change to proper path to word doc

    String output = @"C:\Test\Generated Documents\ACH Form - Generated.pdf";  //change to proper saving path for pdf docs

    if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + output))
    {
        File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + output);
    }

    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test\ACHInformation.json");  //change to get the proper json file
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

    // Initial setup, create credentials instance.
    Credentials credentials = Credentials.ServicePrincipalCredentialsBuilder()
        .WithClientId(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID"))
        .WithClientSecret(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET"))
        .Build();

    // Create an ExecutionContext using credentials and create a new operation instance.
    ExecutionContext executionContext = ExecutionContext.Create(credentials);

    DocumentMergeOptions documentMergeOptions = new DocumentMergeOptions(data, OutputFormat.PDF);
    DocumentMergeOperation documentMergeOperation = DocumentMergeOperation.CreateNew(documentMergeOptions);

    // Provide an input Fileref for the operation
    FileRef sourceFileRef = FileRef.CreateFromLocalFile(input);
    documentMergeOperation.SetInput(sourceFileRef);

    //Execute the operation
    FileRef result = documentMergeOperation.Execute(executionContext);

    //Save the result to the specified location
    result.SaveAs(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + output);

    Console.WriteLine("All Done! \n"); //delete when done with testing 
}
```

However it does not retrieve the test forms or return the json file.  So back to the drawing board.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see the edits